# Difference in de facto currency exposure

Tags: investing, etf, foreign-exchange, investment-strategies

Suppose my main currency is SEK and that I want exposure to EM MSCI. Then I could

A) buy a Swedish passive fund in SEK that is exposed to EM MSCI

or

B) Exchange my SEK for EUR or Dollars and then buy an EM MSCI ETF, for example, one from iShares.

Question1) Does the EUR or Dollar movements during my holding time make a difference in case B, in turn, making by currency exposure different from case A?

I am thinking that I hold stocks in the local currencies in the end and that the EUR or Dollar is just something I pass through having no effect.

Lets stick to EUR

There are 3 crosses EUR/SEK "EM basket"/EUR and SEK/"EM basket" and two-time points t=0 and t=1.

At t=0 there can be no arbitrage and so if I change SEK to EM or SEK to EUR to EM should make no difference. I should still get the same amount of EM stocks(disregarding exchange cost).

Then a couple of years go and I decide to sell the ETF, then the stocks are being sold and exchanged for EUR which I get and change to SEK. Again at t=1 there should be no arbitrage and I should get the same amount of SEK as if I sold the EM stock and exchanged the currencies to SEK.

And so I am thinking that the answer to my question is: No!

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Related https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125448/vusa-is-there-currency-risk

Comment: Related https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48783/should-etf-currency-risk-be-avoided-by-changing-denomination-or-selling-in-a-dif/48784